# How to use detached entitys + version in a JSF Converter

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jpa-2.0, converters

i have a problem with conversion of entitys with a version. I made a simple example to explain my problem because the "real" application is to big and contains many unnecessary things.

**Situation:** I have a web application with primefaces and openjpa. I have 20 components (autocompletes + selectedmenues) that needs a converter and they use persistence entitys.

**Informations:** I only want use jsf,primefaces for it! (Nothing special like omnifaces or something else.) The **Question** is at bottom. This is only test-code. It is **NOT** complete and there are some strange things. But this explain my problem at best.

**Example entity: (Only fields and hashcode + equals)**

```
@Entity
public class Person {

@Id
private Long id;

private String name;

@Version
private Long version;   

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Person other = (Person) obj;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    return true;
}
}
```

**First solution**: My first solution was that i make a own converter for every component.I inject my managed bean there and use the getter from the "value" of the component.

**Bean**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "personBean")
@ViewScoped
public class PersonBean implements Serializable {

private List<Person> persons;
/** unnecessary things **/
```

**xhtml:**

```
<p:selectOneMenu >
<f:selectItems value="#{personBean.persons}"/>              
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

**converter:**

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class PersonConverter implements Converter{

@ManagedProperty(value = "personBean")
private PersonBean personBean;

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        String value) {
    //null & empty checks
    Long id = Long.valueOf(value);
    for(Person person : personBean.getPersons()){
        if(person.getId().equals(id)){
            return person;
        }
    }
    throw new ConverterException("some text");
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object value) {
    //null & Instanceof checks
    return String.valueOf(((Person)value).getId());
}
}
```

**Summary:** This solution works good. But i found that there must be a better solution as an converter for every component.

**Second solution:** I found here on stackoverflow the Global Entity Converter. One converter for all, i thought that was a good solution. ("[p:autocomplete for a global Entity Converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837334/pautocomplete-for-a-global-entity-converter/21837399#21837399)"). I use it and i thought it works fine. **BUT** after a few tests i found another big problem, the version of the entity.

**Problem1 with entity converter:**

I have the version field not in my hashcode or equals (i found nothing about it). I only read this ([The JPA hashCode() / equals() dilemma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031614/the-jpa-hashcode-equals-dilemma)) about it. The problem is that the entity will not replaced in the hashmap and in some cases i get an optimistic locking exception because the "old" entity stays in the hashmap.

```
 if (!entities.containsKey(entity)) {
            String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            entities.put(entity, uuid);
            return uuid;
        } else {
            return entities.get(entity);
        }
```

**Solution:** I thought that i can resolve this problem by adding an interface to my entitys that checks whether a version exists.

**Interface:**

```
public interface EntityVersionCheck {
public boolean hasVersion();
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
@Override
public boolean hasVersion() {
    return true;
}
```

**Converter:**

```
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object entity) {
    synchronized (entities) {
        if(entity instanceof EntityVersionCheck && ((EntityVersionCheck)entity).hasVersion()){
            entities.remove(entity);
        }

        if (!entities.containsKey(entity)) {
            String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            entities.put(entity, uuid);
            return uuid;
        } else {
            return entities.get(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

This solution works for the optimistic locking exception but brings another problem!

**Problem2 with entity converter:**

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{organisation.leader}">
<f:selectItems value="#{personBean.persons}"/>              
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

If a organisation has **already** a leader. It will be replaced with a new uuid if the leader is in the persons - list, too. The leader will be set to null or convert exception because the uuid does not exists anymore in the hashmap. It means he use the converter for the organisation.leader and add the leader to the hashmap. Than comes the persons- List and add all other persons in a hashmap and override the uuid from the organisation.leader if he exists in persons, too.

Here are two cases now:

- When i select a other leader, it works normally.
- If i dont change the "current" selection and submit the organisation.leader tries to find his "old" uuid but the other person from the person list has override it and the uuid does not exists and the organisation.leader is null.

I found another solution for it and this is my final solution **BUT** i find, that is a very very strange solution and i will do this better but i found nothing about it.

**Final Solution**
I add the "old" uuid to the "new" object.

```
 @Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object entity) {
    synchronized (entities) {
        String currentuuid = null;
        if (entity instanceof EntityVersionCheck
                && ((EntityVersionCheck) entity).hasVersion()) {
            currentuuid = entities.get(entity);
            entities.remove(entity);
        }

        if (!entities.containsKey(entity)) {
            if (currentuuid == null) {
                currentuuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            }
            entities.put(entity, currentuuid);
            return currentuuid;
        } else {
            return entities.get(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

**Question: How i make this better and right?**

Comment: Do you really need this kind of converter with an internal cache? You'd better let all entities extend from a base entity which has the entity ID abstracted and then convert on that. See also this answer for a kickoff: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17343582 If you need caching to avoid unnecessary DB hits, you can if necessary just leverage caching to JPA (2nd level with container managed caches such as Infinispan on JBoss servers). It'll automagically decide if it'll return the entity from cache or straight from DB, without need for a `@Version`.

Comment: I missed the question or what you are trying to archive? I do not understand why you are handling versioning in your presentation layer? Do you have a cascading save option on your many-to-one option, e.g does jpa also saves the leader of the organisation? Why else should the exception occur.

Comment: balusc: the "internal" cache should be to avoid extra db access because all my needed objects are in my bean, i see no reasons for extra db access. (I thought that would be better as an extra db access every time.) @djmj: I search a better way to realize this. The version handling is only a workaround for the reasion that there is a same object in the hashmap but with an old version. (It normally wont be replace because ´!entities.containsKey(entity)´ returns true. I edit my first post to explain the exception.

Comment: In other words, 2nd level JPA cache is not an option either and you really need to continue this path using `@Version` and a homegrown cache? Do you absolutely understand what a 2nd level JPA cache is?

Comment: no, that was a misunderstanding. My answer to you was only my reason for my solution. I take a look at the second level cache solution but that needs a bit time and tests of behaviours with the second level cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Solution 1 worked and you just want it more generic:

Holding your instances within scope of a bean you can use a more generic converter by removing the managed-bean lookup from it. Your entities should inherit from a base entity with a identifier property. You can instantiate this converter in your bean where you retrieved the entities.

*Or use a guid map or public identifier if id should not be exposed in html source.*

```
@ManagedBean(name = "personBean")
@ViewScoped
public class PersonBean implements Serializable {

    private List<Person> persons;
    private EntityConverter<Person> converter;

    // this.converter = new EntityConverter<>(persons);
}

<p:selectOneMenu converter="#{personBean.converter}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{personBean.persons}"/>              
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

**Abstract Base Entity converter:**

```
/**
 * Abstract Entity Object JSF Converter which by default converts by {@link Entity#getId()}
 */
public abstract class AEntityConverter<T extends Entity> implements Converter
{
    @Override
    public String getAsString(final FacesContext context, final UIComponent component, final Object value)
    {
        if (value instanceof Entity)
        {
            final Entity entity = (Entity) value;
            if (entity.getId() != null)
                return String.valueOf(entity.getId());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**Cached collection:**

```
/**
 * Entity JSF Converter which holds a Collection of Entities
 */
public class EntityConverter<T extends Entity> extends AEntityConverter<T>
{
    /**
     * Collection of Entity Objects
     */
    protected Collection<T> entities;

    /**
     * Creates a new Entity Converter with the given Entity Object's
     * 
     * @param entities Collection of Entity's
     */
    public EntityConverter(final Collection<T> entities)
    {
        this.entities = entities;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(final FacesContext context, final UIComponent component, final String value)
    {
        if (value == null || value.trim().equals(""))
            return null;

        try
        {
            final int id = Integer.parseInt(value);

            for (final Entity entity : this.entities)
                if (entity.getId().intValue() == id)
                    return entity;
        }
        catch (final RuntimeException e)
        {
            // do something --> redirect to exception site
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setEntities(final Collection<T> entities)
    {
        this.entities = entities;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<T> getEntities()
    {
        return this.entities;
    }
}
```

**Remote or database lookup Converter:**

```
/**
 * Entity Object JSF Converter
 */
public class EntityRemoteConverter<T extends Entity> extends AEntityConverter<T>
{
    /**
     * Dao
     */
    protected final Dao<T> dao;

    public EntityRemoteConverter(final EntityDao<T> dao)
    {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(final FacesContext context, final UIComponent component, final String value)
    {
        // check for changed value
        // no need to hit database or remote server if value did not changed!
        if (value == null || value.trim().equals(""))
            return null;

        try
        {
            final int id = Integer.parseInt(value);
            return this.dao.getEntity(id);
        }
        catch (final RuntimeException e)
        {
            // do someting
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I use dao approach whenever I have to convert view-parameters and bean was not constructed yet.

**Avoid expensive lookups**
In dao approach you should check if the value has changed before doing potential expensive lookups, since converters could be called multiple times within different phases.

Have a look at source of: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/ValueChangeConverter

This basic approach is very flexible and can be extended easily for many use cases.

Comment: thanks for it, i will take a look at this in the next days, too

Comment: i've tried it. It works good and i a good "next step" solution without any version problems. Thanks.